# remote images with json not working

Tags: android

I have a great problem when use listview,load more data and remote images. my project read data from json and when don't call ImageLoader works successfully

but when I use it return fatal error
I have a block of text markup between ///error and ///error 
my code is here :

```
    package com.prgguru.android;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import com.example.webserviceactivity.R;

public class ListViewActivity extends Activity
{
        ListView mListView;
        String worldData = "", adsValues[], strProduce, adsResult = "" , maxId="", subject = "",description = "", guild = "", section = "", avenue = "", shoppingCenter = "", tel = "", mobile = "", img = "";
        JSONObject jsonOb;
        JSONArray jsonArr;
        JSONObject jsonOne;
        List<HashMap<String, String>> searchResult = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> searchResultTemp;
        Integer intKind = 0, intGuild = 0, intSection = 0, intAvenue = 0, intShoppingCenter = 0;

    public static final int progress_bar_type = 0; 
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.searchresult);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent != null) worldData = intent.getStringExtra("adsResult");
        adsValues =  worldData.split("Ý");
        String[] strValueTemp = adsValues[1].split("ï");

        intKind = Integer.parseInt(strValueTemp[0]);
        intGuild = Integer.parseInt(strValueTemp[1]);
        intSection = Integer.parseInt(strValueTemp[2]);
        intAvenue = Integer.parseInt(strValueTemp[3]);
        intShoppingCenter = Integer.parseInt(strValueTemp[4]);
        strProduce = strValueTemp[5];
        if(strValueTemp[5].compareTo("n") == 0) strProduce = "";

        getlList(adsValues[0]);

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        mListView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                    int scrollState) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int threshold = 1;
                int position = mListView.getLastVisiblePosition();
                int count = mListView.getCount();

                if (scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    if (mListView.getLastVisiblePosition() >= count - threshold) {
                        getAdsResult(intKind, intGuild, intSection, intAvenue, intShoppingCenter, strProduce, Integer.parseInt(maxId));
                        getlList(adsResult);
                        mListView.setSelection(position);
                    }
                }
            }

            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public void getlList(String json)
    {
        try
        {
            jsonOb = new JSONObject(json);
            jsonArr = jsonOb.getJSONArray("adsResults");
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++)
            {
                jsonOne = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
                ///////////////////////////////////////////////
                maxId = jsonOne.getString("id");
                subject = jsonOne.getString("subject");
                description = jsonOne.getString("desc");
                guild = jsonOne.getString("guildStr");
                tel = jsonOne.getString("tel");
                if(tel.compareTo("") != 0) tel = tel + " -- ";
                mobile = jsonOne.getString("mobile");
                if(shoppingCenter.compareTo("0") == 0)
                {
                    section = jsonOne.getString("sectionStr");
                    avenue = jsonOne.getString("avenueStr");
                    description = "\n" + description + "\n" + "صنف : " + guild + " -- پاساژ : " + shoppingCenter + " -- " + tel + mobile;
            }
            else
            {
                shoppingCenter = jsonOne.getString("shoppingCenterStr");
                description = "\n" + description + "\n" + "صنف : " + guild + " -- منطقه : " + section + "(" + avenue + ")" + " -- " + tel + mobile; 
            }
            description += "\n";
            img = jsonOne.getString("img");
            searchResultTemp = new HashMap<String, String>();
            searchResultTemp.put("subject", subject);
            searchResultTemp.put("description", description);
            searchResultTemp.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.s));
            ///////////////////////////////////////////
            searchResult.add(searchResultTemp);
        }
        String[] from = {"subject","img","description"};
        int[] to = {R.id.tv_subject,R.id.iv_pic, R.id.tv_details};
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_Result);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
              {
                  int pos = mListView.getSelectedItemPosition();
                  Toast.makeText(ListViewActivity.this, String.valueOf(pos), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
        });
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ListViewActivity.this,searchResult,R.layout.listview, from, to);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

             ///error
        for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
            String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("img");
            ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();

            hm.put("img",imgUrl);
            hm.put("position", i);

            // Starting ImageLoaderTask to download and populate image in the listview 
            imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);
        }
              ///error
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Toast.makeText(ListViewActivity.this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public void getAdsResult(int intKind, int intGuild, int intSection, int intAveune,int intShoppingCenter, String produce, int idClause) 
{
    //Create request
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://admin.arabbros.com/", "searchAdsList");
    //Create envelope
    PropertyInfo requestPI = new PropertyInfo();
    requestPI.setName("kind");
    requestPI.setValue(intKind);
    requestPI.setType(int.class);
    request.addProperty(requestPI);
    requestPI = new PropertyInfo();
    /////////////////////////////////////////
    requestPI.setName("guild");
    requestPI.setValue(intGuild);
    requestPI.setType(int.class);
    request.addProperty(requestPI);
    requestPI = new PropertyInfo();
    /////////////////////////////////////////
    requestPI.setName("section");
    requestPI.setValue(intSection);
    requestPI.setType(int.class);
    request.addProperty(requestPI);
    requestPI = new PropertyInfo();
    /////////////////////////////////////////
    requestPI.setName("avenue");
    requestPI.setValue(intAveune);
    requestPI.setType(int.class);
    request.addProperty(requestPI);
    requestPI = new PropertyInfo();
    /////////////////////////////////////////
    requestPI.setName("shoppingCenter");
    requestPI.setValue(intShoppingCenter);
    requestPI.setType(int.class);
    request.addProperty(requestPI);
    requestPI = new PropertyInfo();
    /////////////////////////////////////////
    requestPI.setName("produce");
    requestPI.setValue(produce);
    requestPI.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(requestPI);
    requestPI = new PropertyInfo();
    /////////////////////////////////////////
    requestPI.setName("idClause");
    requestPI.setValue(idClause);
    requestPI.setType(int.class);
    request.addProperty(requestPI);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    //Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    //Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE("http://admin.arabbros.com/MobileWs.asmx");

    try {
        //Invole web service
        androidHttpTransport.call("http://admin.arabbros.com/searchAdsList", envelope);
        //Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

        adsResult = response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        adsResult = "0";
    }
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{

    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

        InputStream iStream=null;
        String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("img");
        int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(imgUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url                
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url 
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            // Getting Caching directory 
            File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

            // Temporary file to store the downloaded image 
            File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+position+".png");               

            // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
            FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

            // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);             

            // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
            b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);              

            // Flush the FileOutputStream
            fOutStream.flush();

            //Close the FileOutputStream
            fOutStream.close();             

            // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position in the listview
            HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            // Storing the path to the temporary image file
            hmBitmap.put("img",tmpFile.getPath());

            // Storing the position of the image in the listview
            hmBitmap.put("position",position);              

            // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and position
            return hmBitmap;                


        }catch (Exception e) {              
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
        // Getting the path to the downloaded image
        String path = (String) result.get("img");           

        // Getting the position of the downloaded image
        int position = (Integer) result.get("position");

        // Getting adapter of the listview
        SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter ) mListView.getAdapter();

        // Getting the hashmap object at the specified position of the listview
        HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position);   

        // Overwriting the existing path in the adapter 
        hm.put("img",path);

        // Noticing listview about the dataset changes
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to try presenting your problem as an SSCCE: http://sscce.org.  You're much more likely to get help if you do.

Comment: Could you try only posting the areas of code which throw the error, or are associated? What specific error is thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a while, I have the following stuff for you. Since It's not a good way to discuss in comments, I will post them here.

First:

You have this in your code: searchResultTemp.put("img", String.valueOf(R.drawable.s)); (code you provided me), which will set your "img" value to an ID string (not a valid url). This will cause your LoaderTask's doInBackground method failed and returns a null value. In your onPostExecute, you didn't check that null returns, then It cause your app to failure. Please change this (put("img", img) for example, where img is the url you got form json).

Second:

Your json has an entry for "img" attribute, but its value is not a valid http url (it is "dariran.com/ads/mobile/1.jpg" for instance), so, again, your task failed to execute an http request, which will give a null return. Please fix it from your server or whatever will return the Json result.

Third:

This is how you initiated your listview: you defined a getlList method, add a try/catch and put your listview initiation code inside. Once your parsing process failed, for example, some entries doesn't exist, your code will throws an Exception and your listview will never be initiated. This is a bad approach. I suggest you to initiate all your view/activity-based instances inside your onCreate method.

Comment: you are welcome. i also suggest you not to use HashMap that way :D. as for your purpose, you may want to create an Object that will store the neccessary information about img, for example a ImgInfo object with Strings about imgUrl, imgPath and an integer defines its position inside the listview. but just follow the best way that fut you. happy coding!

Comment: thank you, but i'm new in java and don't know what is best way ;)